# Call function in flash CS3

Tags: javascript, flash

I have a flash, and this calls a javascript function.

```
function StoreFlashCookie(value) {
    var flashcookie = document.getElementById("<%=HF_FlashCookie.ClientID %>");
    if (flashcookie.value == "") {
        flashcookie.value = value;
    } else {
        StoreFlashCookie_Flash(flashcookie.value);
    }
}
```

When page is loaded, flash will call that function to assign value for hidden field, or update value saved by itself.

```
function StoreFlashCookie_Flash(value) {
    document.getElementById("flashMovieId").flashStoreCookie(value);
}
```

But I have a problem as when I click a submit button, I process for value and assign it for hidden field and I use javascript submit information to another page in code behind. In firefox and IE, my code work fine, but chrome, I can't call "flashStoreCookie" function. Chrome crash javascript on function "StoreFlashCookie_Flash".

I think my flash to be loaded after my process code in chrome.

Comment: Where does the function `flashStoreCookie` come from?

Comment: flashStoreCookie is function callback in flash

Comment: "I think my flash to be loaded after my process code in chrome." -- I think you're onto the issue, why not test what is returned by `document.getElementById("flashMovieId")` and see if that object is null. If you're not using SWFObject to embed the Flash app, that might help you solve this in a nice browser independent way.

Comment: <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/flash/FlashCookie_GetAndStoreData.swf?v=1"
        width="10" height="10" id="flashMovieId">
        <param name="movie" value="/flash/FlashCookie_GetAndStoreData.swf?v=1" />
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    </object>